# return the most frequent value within columns

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table in SAS where is for example a customer_id and 5 columns with his monthly statuses. There is 6 different statuses for customer. 
For example

```
customer_id   month1    month2    month3    month4    month5 
12345678      Waiting   Inactive  Active    Active    Canceled
```

I want return a value from columns month1 - month5 which is the most frequent. In this case it is the value Active.
So result will be

```
customer_id   frequent
12345678      Active
```

Is there any function in SAS? I have some idea how to do it with sql but it will be very complicated with a lot of case conditions etc. I am new in SAS so I suppose there will be some better solution.

Comment: SQL: Unpivot months, group by customer_id and month, partition by customer_id, order by count desc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an array to split the data set into one observation for each month of a customers history you can use summary functions in proc sql to easily get the most frequent occurrence and use most recent month (assuming that is month 5) for breaking ties.

```
data want1;
    set have;
    array m(*) month1 -- month5;
    do i = 1 to dim(m);
        cid = customer_id;
        frequent = m(i);
        position = i;
        output;
    end;
    keep cid frequent position;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want2 as select
    cid as customer_id,
    frequent,
    max(position) as max_pos,
    count(frequent) as count
    from want1
    group by cid, frequent;
quit;

proc sort data = want2; by customer_id descending count descending max_pos; run;

data want3;
    set want2;
    by customer_id descending count descending max_pos;
    if first.customer_id;
    drop max_pos count;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat poor solution, but it does work for 2 different values, and in this case 5 months. If number of active >= 3, that's the most common value:

```
select customer_id, case when (case when month1 = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end +
                               case when month2 = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end +
                               case when month3 = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end +
                               case when month4 = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end +
                               case when month5 = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) >= 3
                             then 'Active' else 'Waiting' end
from tablename
```

Another way, `UNION ALL`:

```
select customer_id, month, count(*) as cnt
(
    select customer_id, month1 as month from tablename
    UNION ALL
    select customer_id, month2 from tablename
    UNION ALL
    select customer_id, month3 from tablename
    UNION ALL
    select customer_id, month4 from tablename
    UNION ALL
    select customer_id, month5 from tablename
)
group by customer_id, month
order by cnt
fetch first 1 row only
```

Where `FETCH FIRST` is ANSI SQL, may be `TOP` or `LIMIT` for some dbms products.

Comment: Thanks. I have had simmilar idea. But problem is, there can be 6 different values...

Comment: Maybe you could update your sample data? And what result do you expect if it's a tie?

Comment: Sorry but what do you think by tie?

Comment: If there are 2 Active and 2 Waiting (and 1 other).

Comment: Then I want this which was last (in month 5). Same in the case that there is every value only once.